# How to ask user for a callback function

Tags: dart, dart-async

I want to ask user for a callback function (shortened):

```
Future<dynamic> myfunc(dynamic onSuccess) async {
  Completer c = Completer();

  // some time-consuming procedure

  if (onSuccess is Function) {
    c.complete(true);
    return c.future.then(onSuccess());
  } else {
    c.complete(false);
    return c.future;
  }
}

bool should_be_true = await myfunc(print("Success!"))
```

But my code does not work, dartanalyzer throws a following error on the last line:

```
error • The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore cannot be used at example/index.dart:15:35 • use_of_void_result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

- You're passing in the **result** of calling `print`, not a function. Use `() => print('...')` to pass in a function.
- In functions that return `Future`, you want to return ASAP so you're not blocking your caller. This is why I use `scehduleMicrotask`. In general, you should not need to use `Completer`, except for very complex async work. Try to just use async/await.
- You don't need to flag a function using a `Completer` with `async`.

Try this:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<dynamic> myfunc(dynamic onSuccess) {
  var c = Completer();

  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    // some time-consuming procedure

    if (onSuccess is Function) {
      onSuccess();
      c.complete(true);
    } else {
      c.complete(false);
    }
  });

  return c.future;
}

main() async {
  var should_be_true = await myfunc(() => print("Success!"));
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you, I haven't seen Dart for a while and when fixing code from 1.11 to 2.0, even easy things are now harder